# PHP OOP filter validation on email array

Tags: php, arrays, oop, filtering

I'm using a validation class by David Powers (from the book PHP Object Oriented Solutions) for filtering input data. Below is a function to filter a single email address. How do I modify this function to filter an array of email addresses? (I have a dynamic form which may contain a variable number of email addresses and some other data relating to it: both arrays are the same length and these filters should not remove values from the arrays, just to report if any of the values are invalid.)

```
/**
 * Checks whether the input conforms to the format of an email address.
 * 
 * It does not check whether the address is genuine. Multiple addresses are
 * rejected, guarding against email header injection attacks.
 * 
 * @param string $fieldName Name of submitted value to be checked.
 */
public function isEmail($fieldName)
{
    // Check that another validation test has not been applied to the same input
    $this->checkDuplicateFilter($fieldName);
    // Set the filter options 
    $this->_filterArgs[$fieldName] = FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL;
}
```

Here's the function for validating integers. What would it require to make this function accept an array of integers? (I commented out the min, max options from the function. They are not mandatory in this array validator. But feel free to help in one way or another...)

```
public function isInt($fieldName/*, $min = null, $max = null*/)
{
    // Check that another validation test has not been applied to the same input
    $this->checkDuplicateFilter($fieldName);
    // Set the filter options
    $this->_filterArgs[$fieldName] = array('filter' => FILTER_VALIDATE_INT);
    // Add filter options to test for integers within a specified range
    //if (is_int($min)) {
    //    $this->_filterArgs[$fieldName]['options']['min_range'] = $min;
    //}
    //if (is_int($max)) {
    //    $this->_filterArgs[$fieldName]['options']['max_range'] = $max;
    //}
}
```

These were two of the public methods of validation class. Please let me know if I should attach the class constructor or the public function which actually performs the validation. Right now I'm guessing you don't need to see them but my OOP skills are quite poor. Any help is very much appreciated.

UPDATED: added the constructor

```
/**
 * Constructs a validator object for $_POST or $_GET input.
 * 
 * The constructor checks the availability of the PHP filter functions for which it
 * acts as a wrapper. If the optional first argument (an array of required fields) is 
 * supplied, it checks that each one contains at least some input. Any missing items are
 * stored as an array in the $missing property.
 * 
 * By default, the constructor sets the input type to "post". To create a validator for
 * the $_GET array, set the optional second argument to "get".
 * 
 * @param array  $required   Optional array containing the names of required fields or URL variables.
 * @param string $inputType  Type of input; valid options: "post" and "get" (case-insensitive); defaults to "post"
 * @return Pos_Validator object
 */
public function __construct($required = array(), $inputType = 'post')
{
    if (!function_exists('filter_list')) {
        throw new Exception('The Pos_Validator class requires the Filter Functions in >= PHP 5.2 or PECL.');
    }
    if (!is_null($required) && !is_array($required)) {
        throw new Exception('The names of required fields must be an array, even if only one field is required.');
    }
    $this->_required = $required;
    $this->setInputType($inputType);
    if ($this->_required) {
        $this->checkRequired();
    }
    $this->_filterArgs = array();
    $this->_errors = array();
    $this->_booleans = array();
}
```

UPDATE 2: I realized that after filtering any invalid array values are labeled as bool(false). So the function below works but it doesn't generate validation error same way as the single value filter functions do.

```
public function isIntArray($fieldName)
{
    // Check that another validation test has not been applied to the same input
    $this->checkDuplicateFilter($fieldName);
    // Set the filter options
    $this->_filterArgs[$fieldName]['filter'] = FILTER_VALIDATE_INT;
    $this->_filterArgs[$fieldName]['flags'] = FILTER_REQUIRE_ARRAY;

    //is is possible to mark the whole array to false or
    //somehow break the whole script?
}
```

The function above strips away invalid values and database cells are filled with blanks if no other precaution are taken. I think I'll check the validated array (with foreach loop) after filtering and if any of the array values is false, I break the script somehow. (There's no point inserting empty values in the database is they suppose to be valid email addresses or integers.) This solution works for now but I bet there is a more elegant and efficient way to do this. Thank you for your help and suggestions. I'm still open for new ideas.

-Jouni

Comment: Aren't you better off iterating over the array and sending the variables for validation one by one?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. I did make a foreach loop for the array but validation class throws an warning and any value passes the validate input function (basically a PHP's filter_input_array which performs the actual validation and filtering of input).

Comment: What I mean is instead of passing the whole array to the validator (what you are trying to do), why not pass the arrays contents one by one to the validator as it is (dont modify the validator function, modify the calling function). I think the person below talking about `array_map` is saying the same thing. It looks like you have solved it your way anyway so thats good to hear

Comment: @Hank It is impossible to use foreach loop (if that's what you meant) for the validor function if it's meant for validating a single value. I'm not sure why but it generates a warning or error of some sort. So it was necessary to create a new function for validatins an array and an extra function to check the arrays values for false. For now I'm quite pleased for my solution (see my answer to this question, just updated it a little bit). Maybe in the future I understand PHP's filter functions and their flags better. For now I'll stick with these added functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATED, see below.

I think I have a acceptable solution for this so I just answer this little more precisely than in the comments. Here's the whole class but I made some modifications to it.
http://codepad.org/sCC0sruO

First I added a new protected value to the class: `protected $_arrayHasFalse;`

These two validating functions valide arrays of values. They mark the invalid values as false so a little more work has to be done.

```
public function isIntArray($fieldName) {
// Check that another validation test has not been applied to the same input
$this->checkDuplicateFilter($fieldName);
// Set the filter options
$this->_filterArgs[$fieldName]['filter'] = FILTER_VALIDATE_INT;
$this->_filterArgs[$fieldName]['flags'] = FILTER_REQUIRE_ARRAY;
}

public function isEmailArray($fieldName){
// Check that another validation test has not been applied to the same input
$this->checkDuplicateFilter($fieldName);
// Set the filter options
$this->_filterArgs[$fieldName]['filter'] = FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL;
$this->_filterArgs[$fieldName]['flags'] = FILTER_REQUIRE_ARRAY;
}
```

This function checks if any of the array values is invalid. It assigns the arrayHasFalse to `true` if everything is not valid. (This is a minor flaw as it does not remember all the invalid values. But I'm using it in a context where everything should validate or nothing is inserted into database so I am ok with this solution.)

```
public function checkArrayForFalseValues($array){
  foreach($array as $key => $value){
    if ($value == false){
      $this->_arrayHasFalse = true;
    }
  }
}
```

Finally we need a getter function.

```
public function getArrayFalseRevealer(){
  return $this->_arrayHasFalse;
}
```

So this is the deal in the form process file...

```
$val = new validator;
$val->isIntArray('AllShouldBeIntegers'); //dynamically expandable form field
$val->isEmailArray('AllShouldBeEmails'); //dynamically expandable form field

//these are in the original class (pretty self explanatory functions I think)
//validated input is stored in $filtered
$filtered = $val->validateInput();
$missing = $val->getMissing();
$errors = $val->getErrors();

//after the validation we go through a bit more work
$val->checkArrayForFalseValues($filtered['AllShouldBeIntegers']);
$val->checkArrayForFalseValues($filtered['AllShouldBeEmails']);

//mastervalue is set to true if anything is invalid
//maybe this function should be named: $doesAnyCheckedArrayHasEvenASingleInvalidValue
$arrayHasFalse = $val->getArrayFalseRevealer();

//proceed if everything is OK
if (!$missing && !$errors && !$arrayHasFalse) {// Everything passed validation.
  //do the database magic here...
}
```

I guess this does the trick. I'll mark this as an accepted answer. Feel free to comment if you have suggestions for improvements.

Thanks everyone.

UPDATE: Improved the array validator. Let's pass the filter as an argument (or is it a parameter?). It is called for example like this: `$val->isArrayAcceplable('AllShouldBeEmails', 'email');`

```
public function isArrayAcceplable($fieldName, $filter){
//Check that another validation test has not been applied to the same input
$this->checkDuplicateFilter($fieldName);

 //set the desired filter
 //add more options for your convenience
switch($filter){
  case 'email':
    $this->_filterArgs[$fieldName]['filter'] = FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL;
    break;
  case 'int':
    $this->_filterArgs[$fieldName]['filter'] = FILTER_VALIDATE_INT;
    break;
}

//we are validating an array
$this->_filterArgs[$fieldName]['flags'] = FILTER_REQUIRE_ARRAY;
}

//just remember to check the array for false values. (See above.)
```

-Jouni

Answer (score 1):

You could just call the `isInt` function multiple times and have the loop on the outside of the function.  What does the constructor look like?

If you really want to do it you way you could change the function to look something like this:

```
public function isInt( $my_array ) {
   foreach( $my_array as $element ) {
      $this->checkDuplicateFilter( $element );
      $this->_filterArgs[$element] = array('filter' => FILTER_VALIDATE_INT);
   }
}
```

If you like, post the constructor on here and we can show you how to instantiate it and validate your inputs that way instead.

UPDATE (Now constructor has been posted)

What's the name of the class?  Let's assume it's called `Validator` (change to what it is really called)

```
$validator = new Validator( /* Add your optional arguments here */ );

/* change $inputs to the name of the array containing all your inputs */
foreach( $inputs as $input ) {
   // validate each input
   if( $validator->isInt( $input ) ) {
      // int is valid, do something
   } else {
      // int isn't valid, do something else
   }
}
```

Then do something similar for `isEmail` for your e-mail inputs.

Comment: This didn't work. I updated the question and added the constructor. -Jouni

Comment: The first part of your answer generates this message: Warning: filter_input_array() [function.filter-input-array]: Numeric keys are not allowed in the definition array...

Comment: What are you passing the `isInt` function?  (Maybe paste your input on here if it's not large `(print_r( $inputs ));`

Comment: $validator->isInt($array); print_r($array) prints: "Array ( [0] => 0 [1] => 1 [2] => b [3] => 1 )" But now I don't the warning message above. I get an exception: a filter has already being set for...". Should I post more functions of the validation class? It seems that `validate input` function doesn't allow numeric keys. Not sure thought why `checkDuplicateFilter` throws an exception inside a loop. Maybe the problem is in the Numeric keys of an array?

Comment: Ah, are you giving `isInt` the whole array?  That might be why you're getting that Exception.. do a `print` on the argument you pass to `isInt` and make sure it's something like `1` or `a` rather than an array...

Comment: Could I email this whole class to you? Or to someone else interested? I'm now a bit confused why things don't work. There are some functions (at least for sanitizing filters) in this validation class that accept arrays. They work like charm and I would like to be able to use PHP's email filter in the same way.

Comment: Thank you for your help so far. Here's the whole validation class: http://codepad.org/sCC0sruO

Comment: I forgot to address my last reply to you so I'm not sure if you got the link to the code. I also updated my original question. Feel free to comment if you have something more to say. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

you can also use array_map.

From php.net:

```
<?php
function cube($n)
{
    return($n * $n * $n);
}

$a = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
$b = array_map("cube", $a);
print_r($b);
?>
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 8
    [2] => 27
    [3] => 64
    [4] => 125
)
```

So in your case, you'd use:
(Updated to use object)

```
array_map(array($this, $this->isEmail), $emailArray);
array_map(array($this, $this->isInt), $integerArray);
```

Fairly simple I think...

Comment: Sorry, maybe it is simple for you but not for me. I don't get it to work. What kind on function I shoul create in the validation class so I could use `$validator->isIntArray;` on an array of integers?

Comment: That's the thing, with array_map you don't need to create a separate function, you already have isInt and isEmail, so just call `array_map(array($this, $this->isInt), $YOUR_ARRAY);` wherever you were normally checking if a variable is an integer...same for the email.

Comment: I still don't quite understand. Maybe I'm just a bit slow... Please check the original question and second update. Is it possible to use this `array_map` inside that `isIntArray` function in a way it marks the array as false? Thank you for your help.

Comment: The purpose of array_map is to go through each item in the array and apply the specified function to it, so `array_map("function_to_apply",$your_array)` is the same as `foreach($your_array as $key=>$value){function_to_apply($value);}`.  Does that help?

Comment: In other words, array_map doesn't go inside isInt, you pass isInt to array_map as described above.

Comment: Just to make it absolutely clear, replace `$this->isInt($variable)` with `array_map(array($this, $this->isInt),$yourarray)` same for the email check.

Comment: It helps a little but it doesn't work. Maybe I'm still doing it wrong. Numeric keys aren't allowed so the function inside foreach loop should be pointed to `$key`, not `$value`. But it allowed everything to pass. I think I'm happy for my update2 solution but I'll try to understand `array_map` little better in the future. Of course I'll be back if my solution doesn't work well enough... For now it seems to working fine. Only extra thing I have to do is to iterate through validated array and check if anything is false. Thanks again for the help.